# Let $E(n,z)=|z+1|+|z^{2n}+1|$. Find $\displaystyle\min_{z\in\mathbb{C}} E(n,z)$.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Let $E(n,z)=|z+1|+|z^{2n}+1|$. Find $\displaystyle\min_{z\in\mathbb{C}} E(n,z)$.

Here is what I know so far: My suspicion is that the minimum is attained for $z=\cos((2n-1)\pi/2n)+i\sin((2n-1)\pi/2n)$ where $E(n,z)=2\sin(\pi/4n)$. I manged to show this for $|z|\geq 1$; so for the question you can freely assume you are inside the unit disk.

Comment: Are you allowed to use multivariable calculus? If yes then you can describe $z$ in polar coordinates $r,\theta$ and solve for $\nabla E=0$.

Comment: I've tried this. But you will quickly realize how hairy the situation gets when you compute the gradient. Still would be happy if somebody manages to squeeze some precise things out of that.

Comment: Multivariable Calculus won't help. Unfortunately,  the global minimum does not occur at a point where $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} = 0$. For example, for $n=1$, we have the optimal $r=1$ and
$$
E = \sqrt{2 (1+\cos\phi)} + \sqrt{2 (1+\cos(2 \phi))} \ge \sqrt{2}
$$
and the minimum occurs at $\phi = \pi/2$ where $\sqrt{2 (1+\cos\phi)}$ has no defined derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Now first notice that using $z \to -z$ we need to find the minimum of $|z-1|+|z^{2n}+1|$ and then let $w=z-1$ so we need the minimum of $a(w)=|w|+|f(w)|$ where $f(w)=1+(w-1)^{2N}$.

For $w=0, z=1$ we get $2$ and for $f(w)=0, w=1-\omega_k, \omega_k^{2N}=-1, k=1,..2N$ a simple computation shows that half the time we get the OP's proposed answer $2\sin(\pi/4N)$ and half the time $2\cos(\pi/4N)$ which is manifestly bigger (for $N \ge 2$) or same for $N=1$ but always strictly less than $2$. Also by continuity any possible minimum would have $|w| \ge \delta >0$ since at zero we are away from it.

Assume now the minimum is attained at some $w \ne 0, f(w) \ne 0$. Writing $a(w)=r+R, w=re^{i\theta}, f(w)=Re^{i\phi}$ we need $\frac{\partial (r+R)}{\partial r}=0, \frac{\partial (r+R)}{\partial \theta}=0$

Since $R \ne 0$ we can get a local analytic logarithm, so $\log f =\log R +i\Phi$ and taking partial derivatives we easily see that $\frac{\partial (r+R)}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial R}{\partial \theta} =-R\Im \frac{wf'(w)}{f(w)}$ and $\frac{\partial (r+R)}{\partial r}=1+\frac{R}{r}\Re\frac{wf'(w)}{f(w)}$ so we get that at a minimum where $w \ne 0, f(w) \ne 0$ we must have $\frac{wf'(w)}{f(w)}$ is real and equal to $-\frac{|w|}{|f(w)|}$. Taking absolute values we get $|f'(w)|=1$ or $|1-w|^{2N-1}=\frac{1}{2N}$.

In particular $|1-w|=c_N=\frac{1}{2N}^{\frac{1}{2N-1}}<1$ and $|1-w|^{2N}=\frac{c_N}{2N}$. But then for $N \ge 3$ we already have $|f(w)| \ge 1- \frac{1}{2N} > \frac{\pi}{2N} > 2\sin \frac{\pi}{4N}$ so we cannot have a global minimum there.

For $N=2$ we use that $c_2=(\frac{1}{4})^{\frac{1}{3}}, c_2+\pi <4$ so we are good there too.

For $N=1$ we have $|w-1|=\frac{1}{2}$ and $2w(w-1)/(w^2-2w+2)=-c, c>0$ so $2w=2+\alpha, |\alpha|=1$ and $\frac{(2+\alpha)\alpha}{\alpha^2+4}$ real or $\Im(\alpha^2+2\alpha)(\bar\alpha^2+4)=0$ or $\Im(8\alpha+2\bar \alpha+4\alpha^2)=0$ or $6\sin \theta+4\sin 2\theta=0, \Im \alpha =\theta$ which gives $\cos \theta =-\frac{3}{4}$ since clearly $w-1=\pm \frac{1}{2}$ doesn't work (result is larger than $\sqrt 2$); hence $\alpha=\frac{-3 \pm i\sqrt 7}{4}, w=\frac{5 \pm i\sqrt 7}{8}$. $\Re (1+(w-1)^2) >1$ and the result is greater than $\sqrt 2$ so we are finally done!

Comment: This is awesome thank you! I was secretly hoping it would have an elementary proof- this was suggested for a contest for 10th graders.

Comment: I tried to solve it geometrically and one can show that any potential counterexample for a global minimum has $|z| <1$ but very close $1-|z| << 1/N^2$ and $\arg z$ close to $\pi/(2N)$ (by periodicity we can reduce the problem to when we are in the band $\pi/(4N) < \arg z \le \pi/(2N)$) but I couldn't disprove that possibility... I would like an elementary solution too - even $n=1$ doesn't seem that obvious - a little (complex) calculus shows that cannot happen as above (and we get the result directly from calculus, no need to elaborate geometrically)

Comment: Unfortunately,  the global minimum does not occur at a point where $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} = 0$. For example, for $n=1$, we have the optimal $r=1$ and
$$
E = \sqrt{2 (1+\cos\phi)} + \sqrt{2 (1+\cos(2 \phi))} \ge \sqrt{2}
$$
and the minimum occurs at $\phi = \pi/2$ where $\sqrt{2 (1+\cos\phi)}$ has no defined derivative.

Comment: @Andreas You probably missed the point. The answer **proves** that the minimum is indeed $2\sin\frac\pi{4n}$. To do this the answer investigates the stationary points and proves that the value of the function at these point is larger than the true minimum (achieved at a point where the derivative does not exist).