# minimum of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |1+z_k|+|1+z_1\cdots z_n|$ for $n$ even, $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, maxima-minima

> What is the minimum value of $$|1+z_1|+|1+z_2|+|1+z_3|+...+|1+z_n|+|1+z_1z_2z_3...z_n|$$ for $n$ even, $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

I'm trying to generalize [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4497017/398708). I tried to apply the method in [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4497034/398708) to that question, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is still $2$. We use induction on $n$. You've linked the basis case $(n=2)$. Now we make $2$ cases:

**Case 1:** Modulus of at least two of the complex numbers is $1$ or more. Without loss of generality assume $|z_1|\ge1$ and $|z_2|\ge1$. Then
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |1+z_k|+|1+z_1z_2\cdots z_n|&=\color{green}{\sum_{k=2}^n|1+z_k|}+\color{red}{|1+z_1|+|1+z_1z_2\cdots z_n|}\\
&\ge\color{green}{|1+z_2|+\sum_{k=3}^n|1+z_k|}+\color{red}{|z_1-z_1z_2\cdots z_n|}&&(\text{By triangle inequality})\\
&\ge\color{brown}{|1+z_2|}+\color{purple}{\sum_{k=3}^n|1+z_k|}+\color{red}{|1-z_2z_3\cdots z_n|}&&(\because|z_1|\ge1)\\
&\ge \color{purple}{\sum_{k=3}^n|1+z_k|}+|z_2+z_2z_3\cdots z_n|&&(\text{By triangle inequality})\\
&\ge\color{\purple}{\sum_{k=3}^n|1+z_k|}+|1+z_3z_4\cdots z_n|&&(\because|z_2|\ge1)\\
&\ge2&&(\text{By induction hypothesis})\\
\end{align}

**Case 2:** Modulus of at most one complex numbers is $1$ or more. Let that be $z_1$ without loss of generality. Then
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |1+z_k|+|1+z_1z_2\cdots z_n|&\ge\color{green}{\sum_{k=2}^n|1+z_k|}+\color{red}{|z_2z_3\cdots z_n+z_1z_2z_3\cdots z_n|+|1+z_1z_2\cdots z_n|}&&(\because |z_2z_3\cdots z_n|\le1)\\
&\ge\color{brown}{|1+z_2|}+\color{purple}{\sum_{k=3}^n|1+z_k|}+\color{red}{|1-z_2z_3\cdots z_n|}&&(\text{By triangle inequality})\\
&\ge \color{purple}{\sum_{k=3}^n|1+z_k|}+\color{brown}{|z_3z_4\cdots z_n+z_2z_3z_4\cdots z_n|}+\color{red}{|1-z_2z_\cdots z_n|}&&(\because |z_3z_4\cdots z_n|\le1)\\
&\ge\color{\purple}{\sum_{k=3}^n|1+z_k|}+|1+z_3z_4\cdots z_n|&&(\text{By triangle inequality})\\\\
&\ge2&&(\text{By induction hypothesis})\\
\end{align}

## Cases of equality

First we will closely examine the case $n=2$. Allow me to reproduce the (nice) answer to linked question:

If at least one of the variables (say $z_1$) has modulus $1$ or more, then
\begin{align}
|1+z_1|+|1+z_2|+|1+z_1z_2|
&\ge |1+z_2|+|(1+z_1)-(1+z_1z_2)|\\
&=|1+z_2|+|z_1||1-z_2|\\
&\ge |1+z_2|+|1-z_2|\\
&\ge 2
\end{align}
For last inequality, note that equality holds iff $z_2$ lies on the line joining $-1$ and $1$ on the complex plane, i.e. it is a real number with absolute value at most $1$.

The penultimate inequality becomes an equality iff $|z_1|=1$ (or $z_2=1$ which forces $z_1=-1$ anyway).

The first inequality becomes an equality iff $\frac{1+z_1z_2}{1+z_1}$ is non-positive real or $z_1=-1$ (remember $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$ iff $a, b$ and $0$ are collinear with origin on a side, and $|a-b|=|a|+|b|$ iff $a, b$ and $0$ are collinear with origin in middle).

Now $\frac{1+z_1z_2}{1+z_1}=-c\iff 1+z_1z_2=-c-cz_1\iff z_1=-\frac{1+c}{z_2+c}\text{ or }-c=z_2=1$. This implies $z_1$ is real (with absolute value $1$).

Hence, the solution is that one of the variables is $-1$ and other is a real number with absolute value at most $1$.

If both the variables have modulus less than $1$, then the linked answer goes like
\begin{align}
|1+z_1|+|1+z_2|+|1+z_1z_2|
&\geq|z_2||1+z_1|+|1+z_2|+|1+z_1z_2|\\
&\geq|(1+z_2)-(z_2+z_1z_2)|+|1+z_1z_2|\\
&=|1-z_1z_2|+|1+z_1z_2|\geq 2.
\end{align}
Note that the first inequality is strict, because $|1+z_1|>0$ and $|z_2|<1$, so no solution in this case.

**The solution set is thus $\{-1\}\times[-1,1]\cup[-1,1]\times\{-1\}$.**

A similar analysis works on my solution. Again, note the second case gives no solution (because third inequality is strict, since $|1+z_2|>0$ and $|z_3z_4\cdots z_n|<1$).

In two steps in the first case, I use $|z_1|\ge1$ and $|z_2|\ge1$, they become equality to get equality throughout. Also, "all the variables are real in the solution set with absolute value at most $1$" can be proved by induction. I've proved basis above.

Note that my approach in case 1 is to remove two variables (having absolute values at least $1$) while retaining the same expression. If we have at least *two* variables with absolute value strictly less than $1$, we can remove all other variables and then get into case 2 producing no solution. So either all variables are $\pm1$ or one of them has absolute value strictly less than $1$ and others are $\pm1$.

**The solution set thus comprises of all permutations of $[-1,1]\times\{-1\}^{n-1}$.**

Comment: Stating in which cases *equality* holds would be a nice addition to your nice answer :)

Comment: Equality holds when $z_i=-1$.

Comment: It says "three cases" but there are only two cases in the above, and this answer doesn't cover the case when none of them has modulus > 1.

Comment: @SuzuHirose "Case 2" actually covers two cases: modulus of exactly one of the complex numbers is $1$ or more, and modulus of none of the complex numbers is $1$ or more.

Comment: Sorry careless I was looking for what was missing and didn't read it carefully. Anyway it now says "two". Answer seems good.

Comment: @SuzuHirose $\forall i \; (z_i = -1)$ is sufficient but not necessary for the equality.  For example, the equality also holds if one of the $z$s is $0$ and all others are $-1$.  I wonder if there is a simple characterization of the sufficient and necessary condition.

Comment: @L.F. For the case $n=2$ you also have $z_1=-1$, $z_2=1$, etc. I haven't done all the cases.

Comment: @MartinR, performed an addition, hope it is nice!

Answer (score 4):

**Fact 1**: Let $w_1, w_2, w_3 \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|w_3| \le 1$. Then
$|1 + w_1| + |1 + w_2| + |1 + w_1 w_2 w_3|
\ge |1 + w_3|$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

**Fact 2**: Let $w_1, w_2, w_3 \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|w_1| \ge 1$ and $|w_2| \ge 1$. Then $|1 + w_1| + |1 + w_2| + |1 + w_1 w_2 w_3|
\ge |1 + w_3|$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

WLOG, assume that $|z_1| \le |z_2| \le \cdots \le |z_n|$.

We claim that, for each $n\ge 4$ even,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n |1 + z_k| + |1 + z_1 z_2 \cdots z_n|
\ge \sum_{k=1}^{n-2} |1 + z_k| + |1 + z_1z_2 \cdots z_{n-2}|. \tag{1}$$
Indeed, if $|z_{n-1}| \ge 1$, by Fact 2, we have
\begin{align*}
 &|1 + z_{n-1}| + |1 + z_n| + |1 + z_1 z_2 \cdots z_{n-2}\cdot z_{n-1}z_n|\\
 \ge\,& |1 + z_1z_2 \cdots z_{n-2}|;
\end{align*}
and if $|z_{n-1}| < 1$, using $|z_1z_2 \cdots z_{n-2}| < 1$, by Fact 1, we have
\begin{align*}
 &|1 + z_{n-1}| + |1 + z_n| + |1 + z_1 z_2 \cdots z_{n-2}\cdot z_{n-1}z_n|\\
 \ge\,& |1 + z_1z_2 \cdots z_{n-2}|.
\end{align*}
The claim is proved.

Now, repeating the process (1), we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n |1 + z_k| + |1 + z_1 z_2 \cdots z_n|
\ge \cdots \ge |1 + z_1| + |1 + z_2| + |1 + z_1z_2| \ge 2.$$

Also, when $z_1 = z_2 = \cdots = z_n = -1$, we have
$\sum_{k=1}^n |1 + z_k| + |1 + z_1 z_2 \cdots z_n| = 2$.

Thus, the minimum of $\sum_{k=1}^n |1 + z_k| + |1 + z_1 z_2 \cdots z_n|$ is $2$.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

Use @Carl Schildkraut's idea in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4497034/398708).

If $|w_2| \ge 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &|1 + w_1| + |1 + w_2| + |1 + w_1 w_2 w_3|\\
 \ge\,& |1 + w_1| + |w_2|\, |1 - w_1w_3|\\
 \ge\,& |1 + w_1| + |1 - w_1 w_3|\\
 \ge\,& |w_3|\, |1 + w_1| + |1 - w_1w_3|\\
 \ge\,& |1 + w_3|.
\end{align*}

If $|w_2| < 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &|1 + w_1| + |1 + w_2| + |1 + w_1 w_2 w_3|\\
 \ge\,& |w_2|\, |1 + w_1| + |1 + w_2| + |1 + w_1 w_2 w_3|\\
 \ge\,& |1 - w_1w_2| + |1 + w_1 w_2 w_3|\\
 \ge\,& |w_3|\, |1 - w_1w_2| + |1 + w_1 w_2 w_3|\\
 \ge\,& |1 + w_3|.
\end{align*}

We are done.

*Proof of Fact 2*:

We have
\begin{align*}
 &|1 + w_1| + |1 + w_2| + |1 + w_1w_2w_3|\\
 \ge\,& |1 + w_1| + |w_2|\, |1 - w_1w_3|\\
 \ge\,& |1 + w_1| + |1 - w_1w_3|\\
 \ge\,& |w_1|\, | 1  + w_3|\\
 \ge\,& |1 + w_3|.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: +1. Both of these answers are very nice. I just accepted the earlier one.

Comment: @Dan Thanks. Perhaps we can study more variant of the problem.

Comment: Sure. I like how these questions can be restricted to the real numbers (for younger learners) and they're still interesting.

Comment: @Dan It is complicated if one convert the problem to real, e.g. $n=2$, $\sqrt{(1 + x_1)^2 + y_1^2} + \sqrt{(1 + x_2)^2 + y_2^2} + \cdots \ge 2$. Carl Schildkraut's idea is very nice. By the way, I encountered the question below. I don't know if there is similar idea: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4093474/minimum-of-ez-z1z2n1

Comment: @Dan Another variant is the minimum of $|1 + z_1 | + |1 + z_2| + |1 + z_3| + |1 + r z_1 z_2 z_3|$ for positive real number $r$.

Comment: What I meant by restricting to reals is, for example, show that $|1+a|+|1+b|+|1+ab|\ge2$ for real $a,b$. @River Li

Comment: @Dan Fine. I think sometimes the complex skill makes things simple such as Carl Schildkraut's idea. My answer to the aforementioned question is converting it to real.